# JWPlayer will not play streaming video in a PhoneGap

Tags: android, flash, cordova, streaming, jwplayer

i try to implement a rtmp streaming into a android app using phonegap as container, but unlike the usual, jwplayer report this message "error loading player: no playable sources found" anyone know if depends for the android flash support? and in this case which is the best choice to follow to implement a rtmp/rtsp streaming...

Thanks in advance
Alvin

Comment: RTMP is not going to work on mobile devices.

Comment: Any Alternative to implement a streaming rtsp in a not native app in android? maybe using adobe air?

Comment: If you are using JW Player 6.9+ you can use HLS on Android and set the flash androidhls to true.

Comment: i try to figure out how to do it, can you give me a little piece of code with a rtsp flux as example?

Comment: RTSP will not work, RTSP is not supported by Flash or HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use another format/protocol like HLS using m3u8 etc. Flash is not the ideal solution for cross platform streaming. You need to read through jw docs to have a better understanding on why you need to shift toward this better technology and how to use it properly.

About HLS Streaming
https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/en/portal/articles/1430189-about-hls-streaming

Using HLS Streaming
https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/en/portal/articles/1430218-using-hls-streaming

HLS Adaptive Streaming
https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/en/portal/articles/1430240-hls-adaptive-streaming

----**UPDATE**-----

I personally don't use jwplayer for android I use a plugin called https://github.com/raulduran/VideoPlayer.git
It uses the device native video player thus giving you a high level of compatibility and consistent performance. I find that there is an overwhelming number of differences between devices, versions and vendors when it comes to Androids...so I opted for a more native approach.

Comment: so how to use jw player on cordova for android ?

Comment: @greaterKing.Can i use the plugin you mentioned for hls streams on android ?how to use that plugin?

Comment: Yes you can! As a reminder that plugin is designed for use with cordova/phonegap based applications.